# Solving recursion of a complex function

Tags: generating-functions, recurrences

I am trying to find a closed form formula for the following recursive function:
$$f_n(h)= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-2}{i-1} \cdot (0.5)^{n-2} \cdot [ (f_{n-i}(h-1)\cdot \sum_{j=0}^{h-1}f_i(j)) + (f_{i}(h-1)\cdot \sum_{j=0}^{h-2} f_{n-i}(j))] $$
The base cases are the following:
$$ f_1(h)= \begin{cases} 
      1 & h=0 \\
      0 & otherwise
   \end{cases} \\
   f_2(h)= \begin{cases} 
      1 & h=1\\
      0 & otherwise
   \end{cases} 
$$ 
I have been trying to use the generating functions technique, but I have been unsuccessful so far and I was wondering if anyone has suggestions into how to solve this problem. 
Thank you for your help in advance

Edit:
I added the base cases

Comment: If we start with  $f_i(0)=1=g(0)$ we get all $f_i(h)=g(h)$. Then we get a simpler recurrence relation $$g(h+1)=2g(h)[\sum_{i=0}^{h} g(i)]$$. From this we can make a differential equation $\frac{\text{d}^2\text{ln}(g(x))}{\text{d}x^2}=2g(x)$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the base cases when I posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $g_k(m) := \sum_{j=0}^m f_k(j)$. Then the given recurrence becomes
\begin{split}
g_n(h)-g_n(h-1) &= 0.5^{n-2} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-2}{i-1} [(g_{n-i}(h-1)-g_{n-i}(h-2))g_i(h-1)+(g_{i}(h-1)-g_{i}(h-2))g_{n-i}(h-2)] \\
&=0.5^{n-2} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-2}{i-1} [(g_{n-i}(h-1)g_i(h-1)-g_{i}(h-2)g_{n-i}(h-2)].
\end{split}

Consider the generating function
$$G_h(x) := \sum_{n\geq 1} g_n(h) \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}.$$
The initial conditions imply that $G_1(x)=1+x$ and $G_2(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}{12}$.

Then the recurrence takes form:
$$G_h'(x) - G_{h-1}'(x) = G_{h-1}(x/2)^2 - G_{h-2}(x/2)^2$$
or
$$G_h'(x) - G_{h-1}(x/2)^2 = G_{h-1}'(x) - G_{h-2}(x/2)^2.$$
Unrolling the last recurrence, we get that for any $h\geq 2$
$$G_h'(x) - G_{h-1}(x/2)^2 = G_{2}'(x) - G_{1}(x/2)^2=0.$$
That is,
$$G_h'(x) = G_{h-1}(x/2)^2.$$
It seems that there is no simple expression for the solution to this recurrence, although we may notice that $\lim_{h\to\infty} G_h(x)=e^x$.

P.S. For a fixed $h$, the generating function for $f_n(h)$ can be expressed as
$$\sum_{n\geq 1} f_n(h) \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = G_h(x)-G_{h-1}(x).$$

Comment: Thank you for your time and clear explanation. I just have a question regarding $$G_h'(x) - G_{h-1}'(x) = G_{h-1}(x/2)^2 - G_{h-2}(x/2)^2.$$ From the lhs I get $$  \sum_{n\geq 1} (g_n(h)-g_n(h-1) ) \frac{x^{n-2}}{(n-2)!} $$ assuming $$ G_h'(x) = \frac{d(G_h(x))}{dx}$$ and I am not too sure how this equals to $$G_{h-1}(x/2)^2 - G_{h-2}(x/2)^2$$.

Comment: Not sure if this is usable, but for the generating function ${\mathcal G}(x,z):=\sum_hG_h(x)z^h$ from [a formula for Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function_transformation#Hadamard_products_and_diagonal_generating_functions) your relations give$$\frac\partial{\partial x}{\mathcal G}(x,z)=z\int_0^1{\mathcal G}(\frac x2,\sqrt ze^{2\pi it}){\mathcal G}(\frac x2,\sqrt ze^{-2\pi it})dt$$

Comment: @KokoNanahji: This is just an application of the formula for the product of two exponential generating functions.

Comment: Ok, sounds good. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Good point, thanks!