# Solving recurrence of a three variable function

Tags: generating-functions, recurrences

I am fairly new to generating functions and have been trying to solve the following recurrence for a computer science problem. 
$$ f(k,d,n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}  \binom{n-2}{i-1}  \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-2} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{k} f(k-j,d-1,n-i)\cdot f(j,d-1,i)\right)$$
Note that
$$
f:\mathbb{N}^3 \rightarrow [0,1]
$$
with the following base cases:
$$ 
\begin{split}
f(k,d,1)& = \begin{cases} 
      1 & (k=0 \wedge d!=0) \vee (k=1 \wedge d=0)\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases} \\
   f(k,d,2)&= \begin{cases} 
      1 & ((k=0 \wedge d!=1) \vee (k=2 \wedge d=1))\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases} \\
\end{split}
$$ 
and the following domains:
$$
\begin{split}
n &\in \{1,2,3,4,\ldots\} \\
k &\in \{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1,n\} \\
d &\in \{-\infty,\ldots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\ldots,\infty\} \\
\end{split}
$$

From f(k,d,n) and base cases we can derive the following for d<0:
$$ f(k,d,n)= \begin{cases} 
      1 & k=0 \\
      0 & k>0
   \end{cases} \\
$$

I would like to mention that $f(k,d,n)$ can also be expressed as the following:
$$ f(k,d,n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}  \binom{n-2}{i-1}  \left(\frac{1}{2}\right )^{n-2} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{k} f(j,d-1,n-i)\cdot f(k-j,d-1,i)\right)$$

Thank you for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$F_d(x,y) := \sum_{k\geq 0}\sum_{n\geq 1} f(k,d,n) x^k \frac{y^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}.$$
Then the recurrence is equivalent to
$$\frac{\partial F_d}{\partial y}(x,y) = F_{d-1}(x,y/2)^2,$$
while the initial conditions imply
$$F_0(x,0)=x,\quad F_d(x,0)=1\ \text{for}\ d\ne 0$$
and
$$\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}(x,0)=x^2,\quad \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}(x,0)=1\ \text{for}\ d\ne 1.$$

This can be seen as a generalization of your [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/360875).

Comment: Well, I was trying to look at the same problem from different perspective and was hoping to be able to find an "easier" formula for it, since the formula in my previous question did not have non recursive expression.

Comment: @KokoNanahji: The g.f. for $\sum_{k=0}^n kf(k,d,n)$ is $\frac{\partial F_d}{\partial x}(1,y)$. If we denote it as $H_d(y)$, then $H_d'(y) = 2 F_{d-1}(1,y/2) H_{d-1}(y/2)$.

Comment: thank you very much for your quick response. I deleted my question because I figured out a way to simplify $\sum_{k=0}^{n} k \cdot f(k,d,n)$ using the constraint that I forgot to mention which is  $\sum_{k=0}^{n} f(k,d,n)=1$. Let $f(d,n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} k \cdot f(k,d,n)$ then $f(d,n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}  \binom{n-2}{i}  \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-3} \cdot f(d-1,i+1) $